# concurrential use of httpcontext.items

Tags: c#, concurrency, asp.net-core-2.1

```
_httpcontextAccessor.HttpContext.UpdateAskDate(askDate);


 public static void UpdateAskDate(this HttpContext context, DateTime AskDate) => context.Items["AskDate"] = AskDate;
```

to store somedate when i have a query , the _httpcontextAccessor is registered like a singleton but i have always this error, do you have any ideas why?

```
     GraphQL.ExecutionError: Error trying to resolve header. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Operations that change non-concurrent collections must have exclusive access. A concurrent update was performed on this collection and corrupted its state. The collection's state is no longer correct.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryInsert(TKey key, TValue value, InsertionBehavior behavior)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.set_Item(TKey key, TValue value)
```

regards

Answer (score 1):

The context is a bit unclear here but if you are calling `UpdateAskDate` from multiple threads simultaneously, it seems like you should synchronize the access to the `Items` collecton. You could for example do this using a `lock` statement:

```
private static readonly object s_lock = new object();
public static void UpdateAskDate(this HttpContext context, DateTime AskDate)
{
    lock (s_lock) //only allow one thread at a time to enter here
        context.Items["AskDate"] = AskDate;
}
```

Note that you need to use the same lock around all accesses to `context.Items`.